# Apache Solr: query in multiple collections with same fields

Tags: solr, lucene, full-text-search, solrj

I have configured Solr 6.x version with two collections. Almost all fields are same in both docs of both collection. There is very little change in fields, just one or two in both collection.

Now I have to search in both collection at the same time i.e., when I receive a query, it should be searched from both collections. Is it possible in Apache Solr. Due to the possibility of overwriting, I cannot keep all docs in same collection

Comment: So how do you want to handle duplicate unique ids between the collections for the query? Do you want to know the hits from each collection by themselves, or as one, merged result set?

Comment: In either case. It would be better if you give both examples

Comment: Well, one is solvable in Solr - searching it as one large collection, but duplicates will be lost in that case. Since your question explicitly wants to allow duplicates, its important to know why and what limitation that introduces. You can create a collection alias with the Collection API and `CREATEALIAS` - give the `collections` parameter as `collections=col_1,col_2`.